# input vs. raw_input: Python Interactive Shell Application?

Tags: python, shell, undefined, interactive

I was working off of the answer in this question: [Python Interactive Shell Type Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340391/python-interactive-shell-type-application)

My code looks like this

```
def main():
  while True:
    s = input('> ')

    if s == 'hello':
      print('hi')

    if s == 'exit':
      break

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

If I run it, and type hello, I get

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

How should I be listening for text, and calling different functions based on the result?

Comment: python my_shell.py in terminal

Comment: You need [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), not [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) (the latter evaluates what you type as a Python expression).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running it under Python 2.x, where `input()` actually evaluates what you type as a Python expression. Thus, it's looking for a *variable* named `hello`, and, since you haven't defined one, it throws the error. Either use Python 3.x, or use `raw_input()`.

From the parentheses in your `print` I assume you intended to run it under Python 3.x.

Comment: Thank you! I think I would rather force users to call defined variables, but how do I write a my own error message if they input something that is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

```
if s == 'hello':
  print('hi')

elif s == 'exit':
  break

else:
  print('Undefined input')
```

This should take care of undefined user input.

Comment: This seems to work when using raw_input, but when using input python still throws a NameError rather than just printing 'Undefined Input'

Comment: Why don't you use argparse - that is a better way of doing it imo? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/dead-simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results